# Timus Online Judge - 1001 Reverse Root, Runtime error (access violation)

Tags: visual-c++

I have problems to submit my solution, with the error from my topic (Runtime error (access violation)). Could some one help with explanation where am I doing it wrong. The problem explanation can be found here:
http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double outputNumbers[100000];
    double number;
    int index;

    index = -1;
    while (cin.fail() == false)
    {
        cin >> outputNumbers[++index];
    }

    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(4);

    while (index > 0)
    {
        cout << sqrt(outputNumbers[--index]) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You might get that error if they give you more than 100000 numbers.  Consider using a std::vector<double> or increasing the size of outputNumbers to greater than 256K/2, which would be the maximum number of values they will give (assuming all numbers are single digits and have only one character of whitespace separating them)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already submit two solutions both accepted. One with vector as you recommend and the second with stack to check the result ;) and I found that for this problem the vectir class is faster and uses less memory.